# SQLSTATE[HY093] when trying to submit new form

Tags: php

I have created a new form for a new project that I am working on and keep getting the below error message;

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
> does not match number of tokens in

The page loads fine and when I press submit, it gives a HTTP 500 error message.

Error log

```
[Sat Jun 18 13:45:45.833300 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 887942:tid 140534140036864] [client 86.29.27.155:52374] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/vhosts/.com/.com/clients/create.php:74, referer: https://.com/clients/create2.php
[Sat Jun 18 13:45:45.833349 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 887942:tid 140534140036864] [client 86.29.27.155:52374] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: https://com/clients/create2.php
[Sat Jun 18 13:45:45.833356 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 887942:tid 140534140036864] [client 86.29.27.155:52374] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /var/www/vhosts/e.com/k.com/clients/create.php(74): PDOStatement->execute(Array), referer: https://k.com/clients/create2.php
[Sat Jun 18 13:45:45.833378 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 887942:tid 140534140036864] [client 86.29.27.155:52374] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 {main}, referer: https://k.com/clients/create2.php
[Sat Jun 18 13:45:45.833384 2022] [fcgid:warn] [pid 887942:tid 140534140036864] [client 86.29.27.155:52374] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /var/www/vhosts/e.com//create.php on line 74, referer: https://.com/clients/create2.php
```

Code

```
include '../main.php';
check_loggedin($pdo);
$msg = '';
// Check if POST data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $folder     =   "uploads/"; 
    $image      =   $_FILES['image']['name']; 
    $path       =   $folder . uniqid().$image ; 
    $target_file=   $folder.basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType  =   pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $allowed    =   array('jpeg','png','PNG','JPG' ,'jpg','gif');
    $filename   =   $_FILES['image']['name']; 
    $ext=pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) 
    { 
        $msg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF  files are allowed.";
        // var_dump($msg);
    }
    else{ 
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'], $path);
        // var_dump($path);
        $imageSource = $path;

    }
    // Post data not empty insert a new record
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 'auto' ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
    // Check if POST variable "name" exists, if not default the value to blank, basically the same for all variables
    $status             =       $_POST['status'];
    $learner_id         =       $_POST['learner_id'];
    $title              =       $_POST['title'];
    $given_name         =       $_POST['given_name'];
    $last_name          =       $_POST['last_name'];
    $sex                =       $_POST['sex'];
    $date_of_birth      =       $_POST['date_of_birth'];
    $house_number       =       $_POST['house_number'];
    $address_line_one   =       $_POST['address_line_one'];
    $address_line_two   =       $_POST['address_line_two'];
    $city_town          =       $_POST['city_town'];
    $country            =       $_POST['country'];
    $postcode           =       $_POST['postcode'];
    $postcode_enrolment =       $_POST['postcode_enrolment'];
    $phone_number       =       $_POST['phone_number'];
    $mobile_number      =       $_POST['mobile_number'];
    $email_address      =       $_POST['email_address'];
    $ethnic_origin      =       $_POST['ethnic_origin'];
    $ethnicity          =       $_POST['ethnicitys'];
    $health_problem     =       $_POST['health_problem'];
    $health_disability_problem_if_yes   =   isset($_POST['health_disability_problem_if_yes']) ? json_encode($_POST['health_disability_problem_if_yes']) : '';
    $lldd               =       $_POST['lldd'];
    $education_health_care_plan         =   $_POST['education_health_care_plan'];
    $health_problem_start_date          =   $_POST['health_problem_start_date'];
    $education_entry    =       $_POST['education_entry'];
    $emergency_contact_details          =   $_POST['emergency_contact_details'];
    $employment_paid_status             =   $_POST['employment_paid_status'];
    $employment_date    =       $_POST['employment_date'];
    $unemployed_month   =       $_POST['unemployed_month'];
    $education_training_prior           =   $_POST['education_training_prior'];
    $education_claiming =       $_POST['education_claiming'];
    $claiming_if_yes    =       $_POST['claiming_if_yes'];
    $household_situation                =   $_POST['household_situation'];




    // Insert new record into the contacts table
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ?)');
    $result = $stmt->execute([$id, $status, $path, date("Y/m/d"), $learner_id, $title, $given_name, $last_name, $sex, $date_of_birth, $house_number, $address_line_one, $address_line_two, $city_town, $country, $postcode, $postcode_enrolment, $phone_number, $mobile_number, $email_address, $ethnic_origin, $ethnicity, $health_problem, $health_disability_problem_if_yes, $lldd, $education_health_care_plan,$health_problem_start_date, $education_entry, $emergency_contact_details, $employment_paid_status, $employment_date,      $unemployed_month, $education_training_prior, $education_claiming, $claiming_if_yes, $household_situation, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, date("Y/m/d")]);
    // Output message
    if($result == true){
        $details = "All Data Save!";
        // Insert new record into the contacts table
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO client_activity (id,client_id,date,time,details,username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
            $client_activity = $stmt->execute([ null,$pdo->lastInsertId(),date("Y/m/d"),date("H:i:s"),$details,$_SESSION['name'] ]);
            if($client_activity == true){
            $msg = 'Updated Successfully!';
        }else{
            $msg = "Something Missing with Client Activity.";
        }
    }
    else{
        $msg = "Something Missing. Information is not updated!";
    }
}
?>
```

I have looked and the code for a few hours now and can't see the mistake.

Comment: Count the question marks, and count the number of values you're providing to fill them with. Also, consider breaking up your table into multiple smaller tables so you don't need such a long list of columns in the first place. Read up about "database normalisation".

Comment: I was writing an answer then this was marked as a duplicate before I could post, but essentially you have 113 `?`'s passed to `prepare` and 114 parameters passed to `execute`. I think you have an extra null in your list. Stinks that this can't be accepted as the answer now but I hope it helps!

Comment: @AaronMeese - thank you for your help that seems to have fixed the issue :) - I must have miscounted lol